# Error in Kubectl command: The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am trying to run kubectl commands in offline mode but it keeps saying>

```
 kubectl cordon hhpsoscr0001
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

I fail to understand what can be the issue. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Where is the cluster actually running?  Is your `$HOME/.kube/config` file correctly configured?  Is this a programming-related question, or would it make more sense on a different Stack Exchange site like [sf] or [devops.se]?

Answer (score 1):

Please execute : kubectl get svc to see if you get a ClusterIP type output.
If you don't, please configure your kube config properly as @David Maze suggested earlier.